# Simulating key presses aren't working on mac (python)

Tags: python, keyboard, keypress

I have this code which should simulate a key press, but it is not working and I don't know why. My IDE has access to monitor input to the keyboard in system preferences. When I use `keyboard.type("sentence")` it works but does not type the first two characters. I am very confused as to why. Any help is appreciated

```
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller


keyboard = Controller()
time.sleep(2)
keyboard.press('a')
keyboard.release('a')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your IDE have the permission: system preferences/Security & Privacy/Accessibilty? (macOS)

Comment: Thank you so much it works now. I gave it access to the input but not accessibility. I still don't know why it printed sentences except the first two letters with accessibility off but now it prints everything.